# string handling in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I am getting String data from server in the format below. I want to get the value for every tag like `phonenumber` and `name` etc. I am able to convert it in array by comma separator. how to get individual values?

```
Company:Affiliated CO,Organization:TECHNICAL EDUCATION 
SOCIETY,Organization:SINHGAD,Organization:National Basketball Association,Person:Parikshit N. Mahalle,PhoneNumber:81 98 22 416 316,PhoneNumber:9120-24100154,Position:Professor,SportsEvent:NBA.
```

Comment: Why not use JOSN or XML to get you data with some structure?

Comment: First separate the items by the ",", then separate name/value of each item by the ":".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your original string is stored in `rawString`.

You need to :

1) split the string by `,`

```
NSArray *pieces = [rawString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

2) for each item in this array, split it by `:`, and add it to a dictionary :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
for (NSString *piece in pieces) {
    NSArray *splitPiece = [piece componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    // key is at splitPiece[0], value is at splitPiece[1]
    dict[splitPiece[0]] = splitPiece[1];
}
```

Then you'll have a dictionary of what you wanted in the first place.

But as suggested in the comments, it would be far better (and more flexible) for you to receive JSON data.

Edit: your original string shows there are multiple fields named `Organization`. The code I've given is not designed to handle such cases, it's up to you to build upon it.

Comment: Also multiple "PhoneNumber" fields.

Answer (score 0):

If this data is not being returned as a `JSON` object then you'll have to go with @Clyrille answer. But if it is `JSON` then `NSJSONSerialization:JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` will be the way to go.

**EXAMPLE**

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                       JSONObjectWithData:/*urlResponse*/ options:0 error:nil];

NSString *company      = [json objectForKey:@"Company"];
NSString *Organization = [json objectForKey:@"Organization"];
NSString *Person       = [json objectForKey:@"Person"];
NSString *PhoneNumber  = [json objectForKey:@"PhoneNumber"];
NSString *Position     = [json objectForKey:@"Position"];
NSString *SportsEvent  = [json objectForKey:@"SportsEvent"];
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Cyrille I read **"how to get individual values?"**. Does my answer not get individual values if the data is in fact a JSON response?

Comment: The OP does provide an example that is not JSON. If it were JSON it would be invalid because there are two "PhoneNumber" and "Organization" items which would be conflicting dictionary key and this example code would be invalid. Using JSON in place of the current scheme is a good suggestion.

Comment: The data is not in JSON in this case. It's as if I asked how to find some book in my bookshelf, and you told me how to find it on Amazon.